# Can I select hierarchy based on it's name in hiera.yaml file in puppet?

Tags: puppet, hierarchy, hiera

I am using hiera5 and I want to read hierarchies from one of the groups based on their names.
For e.g. Currently I have:

```
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: "/"
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "ABC"
    paths:
      - "env/env-data1.yaml"
      - "env/env-data2.yaml"
      - "env/env-data3.yaml"
```

I want to add multiple hierarchies like this:

```
hierarchy:
  - name: "ABC"
    paths:
      - "env/env-data1.yaml"
      - "env/env-data2.yaml"
      - "env/env-data3.yaml"
  - name: "DEF"
    paths:
      - "env/env-data4.yaml"
      - "env/env-data5.yaml"
      - "env/env-data6.yaml"
  - name: "GHI"
    paths:
      - "env/env-data7.yaml"
      - "env/env-data8.yaml"
      - "env/env-data9.yaml"
```

And read files from just one of the groups at a time lets say just 'ABC'.

Is there a way I can pass hierarchy name as parameter while calling puppet script ?

Additional Info:
I am running a shell script from jenkins which triggers the puppet script.

```
puppet apply --hiera_config=${WORKSPACE}/hiera.yaml ${WORKSPACE}/puppet-script.pp
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add multiple hierarchies like this: [...]

The syntax is fine, but it does not describe multiple hierarchies.  It describes *one* multi-level hierarchy (which is in fact the usual case).  Having multiple levels is what makes it hierarchical -- it is the distinguishing characteristic of Hiera relative to other external-data mechanisms that Puppet has had.

> And read files from just one of the groups at a time lets say just 'ABC'.

Nope, not happening.  Hiera does not work that way.

> Is there a way I can pass hierarchy name as parameter while calling puppet script ?

No, but you can specify a different `hiera.yaml` configuration file, as you already demonstrate.  If you want different hierarchies for different runs then define each in its own (full) configuration file, and choose the appriate config file for each use.

Comment: Thank you John for your reply.
Having multiple hiera.yaml is what my approach currently.